# Getting '-inf' returned from a function

Tags: c++

I've got a simple function 'chs' that will change a positive number to a negative, and a negative to a positive. However, it's for some reason returning '-inf', which I'm assuming means infinite.

Function code:

```
double chs (double token) {
  return (token * -1);
}
```

Main code:

```
chs (-5);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::abs()`? Also; a function returning `void` (nothing) should not `return` a value. This is simply broken code.

Comment: Your function signature declares that it returns `void` but you're returning a `double`. You're then using the result, which is **undefined behaviour**. You should enable (and pay attention to) warnings on your compiler to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: [Cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b87e5083370c7cd) How are you printing this?

Comment: @JesperJuhl What's wrong with std::abs is that it doesn't do what OP wants (i.e. invert the sign of the input parameter)

Answer (score 1):

The function signature returns void.

```
void chs (double token)
```

This means that your function actually doesn't return anything, so whatever you are getting back is undefined.

The fix is to simply replace that `void` with a `double` like this:

```
double chs (double token)
```

Comment: Also, there's no need to multiply by negative one: `return -token;`

Comment: Sorry, the void was meant to be a double. Typo on my part